# Limiting a specific field using Unix?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, debian

So I have a weblog from NASA that logs what hosts requesting for different things on NASA's website. I'm trying to use cut to cut it down to the 2nd most requesting host. I currently have this

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 NASA_access_log_Jul95 | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | head -n 5
```

This shows me top 5 most requesting hosts.

```
cut -d ' ' -f 7 NASA_access_log_Jul95 | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr | head -n 5
```

This shows me the top 5 most requested things that the hosts requested.
I need to find the top 5 things that the 2nd most requesting host requested for. I don't know if any of this seems confusing... I tried my best. If you need any clarifications just let me know. Here's a screenshot if it helps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrskB.jpg

My idea is to limit the first field (the -f 1 part) to the 2nd most requesting host and show me its 5 most requested items some how using cut. However, I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Try filtering logs with `grep <name-of-the-host> file | cut -f7 ...`.

Comment: Don't expect readers to goto remote sites to view your problem description. You should cut/paste exact code/data/output requirements and error messages into your Q and use the {} tool from the menu at the top left of the edit box to format your code/data/errors so they are easily searchable and readable. Otherwise, a reasonable first time Q. Good luck!